# PHP Bash User input

Tags: linux, bash, php, html

I have a bash script that works as. A user inputs a filename and then the script searches through the directories and when its found it copies to another location so that the file gets re-processed again. The script works well on bash script. My problem is that I'm not sure how to process that with PHP so that the user does it through the website or html. Here is my bash script - `user_input.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter required file: "
read file_name

search=`find /var/log -type f -name "$file_name*"`

if [[ $? == 0 ]]
then
echo "$search will be processed soon"
cp $search /root
echo "$search copied for re-processing. Please check after about 5 minutes."
else
echo "Required file $file_name not found"
fi
```

Here is my PHP script, `user_in.php`:

```
<?php
  exec("user_input.sh");
?>
```

Comment: I hope your PHP is not accessible from the internet ... Bash script as user input? Why not a HTML Formular and pure PHP solution ? Webserver has access to `/var/log` and to `/root` ?!

Comment: The bash script will be called with the user permissions of the php daemon. The script may not be able to read directories you require.

Comment: You could set up a timed (crontab) script to do the search.  Use the PHP to just add a file name to a waiting list. In a file or a database.

Comment: Besides the security concerns, This will not work the input of the php is already processed, you need convert the process in the bash shell to php